# ERROR : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to launch the browser through TestNG with Selenium 2.0.

Please look into the below code & need your kind assistance.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Annotations {

    @Test
    public void openBrowser(){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: We can add System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "location of your geckodriver.exe") before calling WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Thanks. As I am using selenium 2.0 hope geckodriver is not required. Though I've tried adding the above line I am getting different error. 
ERROR:  FAILED: openBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:22105
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'VENKATESH-PC', ip: '192.168.43.51', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: Try putting geckodriver.exe in your windows path variable in System Environment variables. Or, you can check by downgrading your geckodriver.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your browser version as well. because selenium 2.X not support firefox 47+ versions.